# Delete all pdf files in a folder using python

Tags: python, pdf, removeall

I am trying to **convert all pdf files to .jpg files** and then **remove them from the directory**. I am able to convert all pdf's to jpg's but when I try to delete them, I get the error "The process is being used by another person".

Could you please help me?

Below is the code

## Below script wil convert all pdfs to jpegs and storesin the same location.

```
for fn in files:
    doc = fitz.open(pdffile)
    page = doc.loadPage(0)  # number of page
    pix = page.getPixmap()
    fn1 = fn.replace('.pdf', '.jpg')
    output = fn1
    pix.writePNG(output)
    os.remove(fn) # one file at a time.

path = 'D:/python_ml/Machine Learning/New folder/Invoice/'

i = 0
for file in os.listdir(path):
    path_to_zip_file = os.path.join(path, folder)

    if file.endswith('.pdf'):
        os.remove(file)
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

As @K J noted in their comment, most probably the problem is with files not being closed, and indeed your code misses closing the `doc` object(s).

(Based on the line `fitz.open(pdffile)`, I guess you use the [pymupdf](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/document.html#Document) library.)

The problematic fragment:

```
    doc = fitz.open(pdffile)
    page = doc.loadPage(0)  # number of page
    pix = page.getPixmap()
    fn1 = fn.replace('.pdf', '.jpg')
    output = fn1
    pix.writePNG(output)
```

...should be adjusted, e.g., in the following way:

```
    with fitz.open(pdffile) as doc:
        page = doc.loadPage(0)  # number of page
        pix = page.getPixmap()
        output = fn.replace('.pdf', '.jpg')
        pix.writePNG(output)
```

(Side note: the `fn1` variable seems to be completely redundant so I got rid of it. Also, shouldn't `pdffile` be replaced with `fn`? What `pdffile` actually is?)

Comment: Hi @Zuo,Thanks for the reply, It was very helpful, pdffile is my mistake and it should be fn. Could you please help me in adding a logic where this code should get executed only if .pdf exists in my folder?